# Increase width of bootstrap popover with JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to increase the width and add custom positioning to a bootstrap popover, that shows up when a page is loaded. I am using the following JS/Jquery code to achieve this...

```js
 <script>
 $('#updatePopover').popover({
    'placement':'bottom',
 'width':'200px',
 'top' : '25opx',
 'html':'true',
 'title':'While you were gone...',
    'content':'Look at me!<br>5 New <strong>Notifications</strong>'
}).popover('show');
</script>
```

```html
<li class="dropdown">
          <a id="updatePopover" href="#"  class="dropdown-toggle custom-dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#div-header-submenu" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img alt = "" class="img-profile-pic img-circle" src="images/profile-pic.fw.png"/>  <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

What is happening is that all attributes are working fine, but it's not changing the width of a the popover, nor is it affecting the position. Also, any help on how I can hide it after a few seconds would be great. I already did some research in hiding the popover, but it doesn't apply to this particular situation.

thanks all!

Comment: Could you show us the HTML code as well?

Comment: Use JSFiddle and show us the full code involved so we can see what you see on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the exact effect you are going for, but you can insert a custom class on the "show.bs.popover" event, and add css for that custom class, as shown below:

```js
var PO = $('#updatePopover').popover({
  'placement': 'bottom',
  'html': 'true',
  'title': 'While you were gone...',
  'content': 'Look at me!<br>5 New <strong>Notifications</strong><br><em>and 300px width...</em>'
}).on("show.bs.popover", function() {
  $(this).data("bs.popover").tip().addClass("my-popover");
});

PO.popover('show');
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}
li {
  list-style: none
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
.img-profile-pic {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.popover.my-popover {
  width: 300px !important;
  margin-top: 20px !important;
}
.popover.my-popover .arrow {
  left: 8.8% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<li class="dropdown">
  <a id="updatePopover" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle custom-dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#div-header-submenu" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <img alt="" class="img-profile-pic img-circle" src="https://getmdl.io/templates/dashboard/images/user.jpg" /> <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
</li>
```